# pySerial and Arduino communication

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

So far, I was exploring Python with Arduino using pySerial. I made some projects where pySerial reads something from the serial port.

```py
import serial 

arduinoSerialData = serial.Serial('com11',9600) #Create Serial port object called arduinoSerialData


while (1==1):
    if (arduinoSerialData.inWaiting()>0):
        myData = arduinoSerialData.readline()
        print (myData)
```

```cpp
int trigPin=13; //Sensor Trig pin connected to Arduino pin 13
int echoPin=11;  //Sensor Echo pin connected to Arduino pin 11
float pingTime;  //time for ping to travel from sensor to target and return
float targetDistance; //Distance to Target in inches
float speedOfSound=776.5; //Speed of sound in miles per hour when temp is 77 degrees.

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW); //Set trigger pin low
  delayMicroseconds(2000); //Let signal settle
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH); //Set trigPin high
  delayMicroseconds(15); //Delay in high state
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW); //ping has now been sent
  delayMicroseconds(10); //Delay in low state

  pingTime = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);  //pingTime is presented in microceconds
  pingTime=pingTime/1000000; //convert pingTime to seconds by dividing by 1000000 (microseconds in a second)
  pingTime=pingTime/3600; //convert pingtime to hourse by dividing by 3600 (seconds in an hour)
  targetDistance= speedOfSound * pingTime;  //This will be in miles, since speed of sound was miles per hour
  targetDistance=targetDistance/2; //Remember ping travels to target and back from target, so you must divide by 2 for actual target distance.
  targetDistance= targetDistance*63360;    //Convert miles to inches by multipling by 63360 (inches per mile)

  Serial.println(targetDistance);

  delay(100); //delay tenth of a  second to slow things down a little.
}
```

For now, my code looks something like this. How can I make use of my ultrasonic sensor in Python and send signals to my Arduino program? In other words, can I make my Arduino file read from the Python file that I have or it is only one direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pySerial allows for communication over serial in both directions. On the Arduino side, you need to call `Serial.read` where appropriate to read data stream from Python. In Python, you just need to send data using the function `serial.write`. If using Python 3, input to `serial.write` needs to be in `byte` format.

Comment: Could I control the robot with python?

Comment: I don't know anything about this robot. But if you can communicate over a serial connection, I presume yes.